# Converting mixed object/array to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've searched for answers to this on SO, but perhaps I'm not asking the right question because I haven't found the answer (yet I know there's probably many examples).

I have this array with objects:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#424 (3) {
    ["AC"]=>
    string(6) "Active"
    ["CL"]=>
    string(6) "Closed"
    ["OH"]=>
    string(7) "On Hold"
  }
}
```

I am trying to reformat it so the end result is this, so it can be inserted into my multi-select widget datasource:

```
[
    {
        "value": "AC",
        "text": "Active"
    },
    {
        "value": "OH",
        "text": "On Hold"
    },
    {
        "value": "CL",
        "text": "Closed"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$newObjectsArray = array();
foreach($objectsArray as $index => $object){
    foreach($object as $key => $value){
        $newObjectsArray[$index][] = array("value" => $key, "text" => $value);
    }
    $newObjectsArray[$index] = json_encode($newObjectsArray[$index]);
}
```

`$newObjectsArray` now holds the converted objects

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not, yet, as I think my widget actually needs the explicit "value" and "text" properties before the values.

Comment: @deaddancer that's why I edited it, it does that now

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a bunch, I was spinning my wheels for a little while on this.